# Perl -e field substitution

Tags: perl

I am using perl -e to convert a hexadecimal number(523cc261) to a meaningful date:

```
perl -e 'my $t=localtime 0x523cc261; print $t . "\n"' 
Fri Sep 20 21:47:13 2013
```

However i am not able to script it as above code needs the value to be provided on prompt.I tried substituting `523cc261` with a variable but it does not work:

```
b=523cc261
perl -e 'my $t=localtime 0x`echo b`; print $t . "\n"`
Backticks found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "0x`echo b`"
        (Missing operator before `echo b`?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "0x`echo b`"
```

My question is how to provide the decimal value(`523cc261`) via argument in a script.

Comment: `0x` is not an operator. `0x523cc261` as a whole is number literal.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way will be to pass the time to the Perl script as an argument. I've rewritten the script to be a little more concise, too:

```
% b=523cc261
% perl -E 'say scalar localtime hex $ARGV[0]' $b
Fri Sep 20 14:47:13 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ENV HASH :

```
$ b=523cc261 perl -le 'my $t = scalar localtime hex $ENV{"b"}; print $t;'
```

Another solution (a bit obfuscated, `$b` is a shell variable) :

```
$ b=523cc261 perl -le 'my $t = scalar localtime hex "'$b'"; print $t;'
```

Comment: The `$%ENV` version has the added benefit of working on Windows.